# how to get an array into another array with a button in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

so i have an array

```
const products = [{
    name: "14K bracelet",
    id: "1",
    description: "Beautfull 14K gold Bracelet",
    price: 100.00,
    
  }]
```

im trying to make it so whenever someone presses this button

```
<Button className="btn btn-primary btn-rings" href="#" onClick={() => cart}>Add To Cart</Button>
```

, it gets added to this array/state

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
```

does anyone know how i would do this,

also how would i get whats showing in the carts, to show up in here

```
{products.map((products) => <h1 key={products.id} className="price>{"$" + products.price}</h1>)}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click a button you need to set the state using useState hooks which you have defined above.
Hope this solves your problem

```
<Button className="btn btn-primary btn-rings" href="#" onClick={() => setCart(products )}>Add To Cart</Button>
```

Comment: ok thanks, do you know how i would make whats in the setCart show up for this             {products.map((products) => <h1 key={products.id} className="price">{"$" + products.price}</h1>)}

Comment: Now when you set the products value in setCart, you can map using cart.
cart.map((products)=>{
 <h1 key={products.id} />
})

Comment: ok i did that but now im getting this error.     TypeError: _BraceletCards__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.map is not a function

Comment: update the onClick to  `onClick={() => setCart(cart => [products, ...cart])}`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `.map()` to render the products. You just have to add the product to your list of items.

```js
{
  { products.map(product => (
    <Button key={product.id} onClick={() => setCart(cart => [product, ...cart])}>
      Add To Cart
    </Button>
  ))}
}
```

You should probably get yourself more familiar with state hooks also: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: would you be able to let me know how i can do the thing that i asked in my new edit

Comment: I changed `product.map` to `products.map` for less confusion. I don't quite understand your new question though? If you want to render your cart items instead, just change the variable to `cart`

Comment: About rendering lists: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: yea i did change it to cart but now it is saying TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')